# Switching between UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a main window (Window based application) and two different UIViewController. i am calling viewController1 in without any problem.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

}
```

there is a button on viewController1, when i press to button I want to remove viewController1 from mainWindow and add viewController2 without using navigation controller.

any help would be appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rootViewController` property of the `UIWindow` object. Create and set the first view controller as the `rootViewController` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[[FirsViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

And change it in the button tap method

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController * viewController = [[[SecondViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    CGRect frame = viewController.view.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 20); // To account for the status bar. Otherwise the gap is at the bottom during animation that adjusts after it completes.
    viewController.view.frame = frame;
    [UIView transitionWithView: self.view.window
                      duration: 0.5
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    animations:^{
                        self.view.window.rootViewController = viewController;
                    }
                    completion: NULL];
}
```